# Linq to SQL OrderBy issue

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I know this question has been asked many times and I know that the Distinct call destroys the previous order so I must use the OrderBy afterwards, but in this case I must be doing something else wrong.

```
int[] resources = (from a in context.Beamline_Requests
                   join b in context.Technique_Requests on a.Technique_Request_ID equals b.ID
                   where b.Beamtime_Request_ID == id
                   select a.Beamline_ID).Distinct().OrderBy(a => a.ID).ToArray();
```

I receive the:

> Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'System.Linq.Expressions.LambdaExpression' because it is not a delegate type

error message on the `OrderBy`.  It also says:

> 'int' does not contain a definition for 'ID' and no extension method 'ID' accepting a first argument of type 'int' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

So apparently the 'a' is no longer part of the context.

I have done similar things successfully but in those cases I am projecting the Linq into a ViewModel so in this case it must have something to do with attempting to just make it an array.

Answer (score 4):

You are only selecting field `Beamline_ID` and later you are trying to `OrderBy  ID`, Your intermediate result from select doesn't have field `ID` it is just a projection of `int` numbers. [As @GrantWinney suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23368835/linq-to-sql-orderby-issue/23368881?noredirect=1#comment35794452_23368881) you can do `OrderBy(a=> a)` like:

```
int[] resources = (from a in context.Beamline_Requests
                   join b in context.Technique_Requests on a.Technique_Request_ID equals b.ID
                   where b.Beamtime_Request_ID == id
                   select a.Beamline_ID).Distinct().OrderBy(a => a).ToArray();
```

For the comment:

> My issue though is that I actually do need to order by the ID, not the
>   Beamline_ID even though I only need the Beamline_ID in the array.

```
int[] resources = (from a in context.Beamline_Requests
                   join b in context.Technique_Requests on a.Technique_Request_ID equals b.ID
                   where b.Beamtime_Request_ID == id
                   select new 
                   { 
                       Beamline_ID = a.Beamline_ID,
                       ID = b.ID
                   })
                   .OrderBy(a => a.ID)
                   .Select(r=> r.Beamline_ID)
                   .Distinct()
                   .ToArray();
```

Or in a simpler version you can achieve:

```
int[] resources = (from a in context.Beamline_Requests
                   join b in context.Technique_Requests on a.Technique_Request_ID equals b.ID
                   where b.Beamtime_Request_ID == id
                   orderby b.ID
                   select a.Beamline_ID)
                   .Distinct()
                   .ToArray();
```

Comment: Ok that makes sense.  My issue though is that I actually do need to order by the ID, not the Beamline_ID even though I only need the Beamline_ID in the array.  How would I go about doing that?

Comment: @SteveGiordano, in that case select an anonymous type, with both `Beamline_ID` and `ID` , then order by `ID` , then just select `Beamline_ID` and then apply distinct. Updated the answer with the code

Comment: @SteveGiordano, also put in a simpler version, which I believe would do the same thing

Comment: @Habib, Your simplified version is what I had originally tried but when the Distinct comes after the orderby, the order is lost.  It seems that this may happen in the first case as well since again the Distinct is coming after the OrderBy...but I will give it a try.

Comment: @Habib I was able to make it work by slightly rearranging your first suggested answer.
`.Distinct().OrderBy(a -> a.ID).Select(r=> r.Beamline_ID).ToArray();`